# How to get the first vertex normal of a fragment in fragment shader in GLSL

Tags: glsl

I know that I can get vertex normal in vertex shader from gl_Normal.

Now I want to set up the color of a fragment to be the vertex normal of its first vertex. May I ask how can I do that? How can I know how many vertex the fragment has, and what is the position and normal for each vertex in fragment shader?

Answer (score 3):

What you ask is not quite possible, but you might be able to get close enough.

You cannot get the normal from the 'first vertex' of a primitive. What you can do is pass the normal from the vertex shader to the fragment shader as a varying, but then each fragment will get a normal that is interpolated from each vertex of the polygon.

You can't access specific properties of the vertex from the fragment shader, only interpolated values.

==EDIT==

Looks like I might be incorrect in some cases, see below comments.

Comment: You can define the varying to be interpolated `flat`, though, which indeed uses the value of a single vertex for the whole triangle, but I'm not sure if it's the first, last or undefined. But this is only available in newer GLSL versions, I think (GL 3+ maybe).

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks, didn't know that. Looks like it might be the last vertex by default:     *The provoking vertex of a primitive is the vertex that determines the constant primary and secondary colors when flat shading is enabled.

    In OpenGL, the provoking vertex for triangle, quad, line, and
    (trivially) point primitives is the last vertex used to assemble
    the primitive.  The polygon primitive is an exception in OpenGL where
    the first vertex of a polygon primitive determines the color of the
    polygon, even if actually broken into triangles and/or quads.*

Comment: You can change provoking vertex by call glProvokingVertex(GL_LAST_VERTEX_CONVENTION) but it is available in OGL 3.2 and later versions.